# Why my IMEI number is always 0000000000000 in the simulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi (and sorry for my bad english),

I try to get the Eclipse emulator's IMEI number, but it's always null, although I succeed to get "0000000000000" 3 days ago (I don't know what I changed meanwhile)

```
private String IMEI = null;

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
IMEI = tm.getDeviceId(); // empty
```

I didn't forget the persmission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

THe emulator wouldn't have an IMEI assigned to it..... the value is probably ok. Try it on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
TelehponyManager manager = (TelehponyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = manager.getDeviceId();
```

This code works perfectly fine on a real device, however under emulator IMEI is always all-zero and it’s not configurable.